# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modeladapter'

Tags: python, machine-learning, libraries, modulenotfounderror, pylance

So I want to run a repo i cloned from github project that is used to segregate the medical reports data and categorise it using machine learning and an error occurred.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import modeladapter as ModelAdapter
```

VSCode screenshot:
[image: Here is the VSCode screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This means that the module does not exist on your PC in the area where Python modules are installed. You should try to install the module using pip and it should resolve I think. I don't know what the module is though, I tried googling it and couldn't find anything, so maybe somewhere on the GitHub repo page it says what the required modules are and where to get them?